# Android can't login. isSBSettingEnabled false

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So, currently I'm developing some app for android and it has some login features. I use volley for my login features. My app used to be fine, but suddenly it can't login anymore. I don't modify any of my codes. I don't know what's the problem. The logcat not showing any errors, it just show you this

```
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 94 with tag 355f91800000000{55965976,0} uid -1, pid: 2402, getuid(): 10231
```

I've checked manfiest for internet permissions and it's not the problem. I've checked the XAMPP and also it's not the problem. What's wrong with my app?

Just for some information, i run my app on Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime. Maybe it can help. Any answers are aprreciated. Thanks..

**Edit**
The code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
Button btnLogin;

String username, password;

String URL = "http://192.168.1.4/zakat/login.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login();
        }
    });
}


private void login() {
    username = etUsername.getText().toString();
    password = etPassword.getText().toString();

    StringRequest login = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login sukses", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login gagal. " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };

    login.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 50000;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 50000;
        }

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

        }
    });

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    rq.add(login);
}
```

}

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: Add some code where you are creating connection with XMPP. so we can help.

Comment: edit: added code